# How to disable Android Studio update notification?

Tags: android-studio

I don't want to update to 2.3 (they broke *Instant Run* for 4.4.4 Devices, now it only works for 5.* and higher)

Just want to hide the notification:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Android Studio then File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Notifications

Then uncheck "Display baloon notifications"

Answer (score 7):

it is ok and for android studio you try it :
1.Open the Preferences window by clicking File > Settings (on Mac, Android Studio > Preferences).

2.In the left panel, click Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Updates.

3.Be sure that Automatically check for updates is checked, then select a channel from the drop-down list (see figure 1).

Click Apply or OK.

[image]

happy code!

Comment: for more information go to android developer site :https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update

Comment: While the other answers are useful, this is what I really wanted--to turn off those notifications about canary releases!

Answer (score 4):

**File** -> **Settings** (or **Android Studio** -> **Preferences** for macOS) -> **Appearance & Behavior** -> **Notifications**.
In the *Group* column you'll find groups like `Android Gralde Upgrade Notification` and `Plugins Updates` etc. Just Change the corresponding *Popup* column to be *No popup*.

If you are not sure which group you should configure, maybe you can wait until a notification appear, record its title, and then find a group in the preference UI mentioned above which is most related to that title.

Comment: `Android Gralde Upgrade Notification` and  `Plugins Updates` in Android 3.5.1.

Comment: @Daniel you are right, the group names have changed as the IDE evolved. I would edit my answer.