# How do I turn off beta release notifications for android studio?

Tags: android-studio

[image: img_notification]

I want to turn off notifications for beta versions only. Is it possible?
I'm using Android Studio 4.1.1.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42745957/how-to-disable-android-studio-update-notification

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To stop getting updates for the beta version only or if you want to stop all updates related to android studio follow the following steps:

1-Click on File from top menu then -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Updates

2-Uncheck Automatically check for updates if you don't want the updates or select a suitable channel for which you only wants the updates

And if you don't want to see notifications you can hide them from settings as mentioned below.

1-Click on File from top menu then -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Updates

2-uncheck "Display balloon notifications" from top

You can uncheck other notifications also if you don't want them.

Comment: This is not correct.  See the comment from @MirRahedUddin above, specifically, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51722747/301703

Comment: @Noel you are right this can be done though I didn't try it we can uncheck or select the suitable channel for notification.
I'm updating my answer